# python: converting numbers to words

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a code that will convert numbers to words, up to 999 trillion. here is my code so far. it works up to 119, but after that things get messy. I can't use append or enumerate. I'm stuck on how to print the larger numbers; how would I format a number like 978,674,237,105?

```
NUMBERS = ["zero", "one", "two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine",
               "ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fiveteen","sixteen",
               "seventeen","eightteen","nineteen"]

TENS = ["", "", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty",
            "ninety"]

HUNNITS = ["","hundred","thousand","million","billion","trillion"]

n = eval(input("What is the number the you want to convert? "))

def convert():
    if n >= 20:
        tens = n // 10
        units = n % 10

        if units != 0:
            result = TENS[tens] + "-" + NUMBERS[units]
        else:
            result = TENS[tens]
    else:
        result = NUMBERS[n]

    print (result)

def convert2():
    if n >=100:
        tens2 = n//100
        units2 = n%100

        if units2 != 0:
            result2 = HUNNITS[tens2] + "-" + TENS[tens2] + "and" + NUMBERS[units2]
        else:
            result2 = HUNNITS[tens2]
    else:
        result2 = HUNNITS[n]

    print(result2)

def main():
    if n >=20 and n< 100:
        x = convert()
    if n >=100:
        y = convert2()

main()
```

Comment: Please don't use `eval(input())`, cast the input to integer (or float).

Answer (score 4):

This can easily be done recursively:

```
def as_words(n):
    """Convert an integer n (+ve or -ve) to English words."""
    # lookups
    ones = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four',
            'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 
            'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen',
            'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen']
    tens = ['zero', 'ten', 'twenty', 'thirty', 'forty',
            'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety']
    # negative case
    if n < 0:
        return "minus {0}".format(as_words(abs(n)))
    # 1000+
    for order, word in [(10**12, "trillion"), (10**9, "billion"),
                        (10**6, "million"), (10**3, "thousand")]:
        if n >= order:
            return "{0} {1}{2}".format(as_words(n // order), word,
                                       " {0}".format(as_words(n % order))
                                       if n % order else "")
    # 100-999
    if n >= 100:
        if n % 100:
            return "{0} hundred and {1}".format(as_words(n // 100), 
                                                as_words(n % 100))
        else:
            return "{0} hundred".format(as_words(n // 100))
    # 0-99
    if n < 20:
        return ones[n]
    else:
        return "{0}{1}".format(tens[n // 10],
                               "-{0}".format(as_words(n % 10)) 
                               if n % 10 else "")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to  discourage you, but this problem has already been solved. There is a neat Python module to do this, called `num2words`

Here is the [link to the GitHub repository](https://github.com/savoirfairelinux/num2words)

And [here is the actual script](https://github.com/savoirfairelinux/num2words/blob/master/num2words/lang_EN.py) for the English language (it supports multiple languages). There you can get some inspiration to fix your script if still needed.

Comment: I'm aware, but I'm trying to do it without using that module. thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

I  wrote this for project euler using lists originally and using python 2 . There may well be bugs I have not tested it too much but it should hopefully help you along

```
nums = ["", "one", "two", "three", "four",  "five",
    "six", "seven", "eight", "nine "]
teens = ["", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen",  "fourteen",
    "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"]
tens = ["", "ten", "twenty", "thirty", "forty",
    "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"]
thousands = ["","thousand", "million",  "billion",  "trillion"]
def num_to_words():
    n= int(input("Enter number to convert: "))
    words = ""
    if n == 0:
        words += "zero"
    else:
        numStr = "%d" % n
        groups = (len(numStr) + 2) // 3
        numStr = numStr.zfill(groups * 3)
        for i in range(0, groups*3, 3):
            h = int(numStr[i])
            t = int(numStr[i+1])
            u = int(numStr[i+2])
            g = groups - (i // 3 + 1)
            if h >= 1:
                words += nums[h]
                words +=  " hundred "
                words+=" "
                if int(numStr) % 100:   # if number  modulo 100 has remainder  add "and" i.e one hundred and ten
                    words+=" and "
            if t > 1:
                words+= tens[t]
                if u >= 1:
                    words+= nums[u]
                    words+=" "
            elif t == 1:
                if u >= 1:
                    words+= teens[(u)]
                else:
                    words+= tens[t]
                    words+=" "
            else:
                if u >= 1:
                    words+= nums[u]
                    words+=" "

            if g >= 1 and (h + t + u) > 0:
                words+= thousands[g]
                words+=" "
    return words
In [7]: num_to_words()
Enter number to convert: 12399990
Out[7]: 'twelvemillion three hundred   and ninetynine  thousand nine  hundred   and ninety'
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Python 3.x:

```
print('Type any number here: ')
number = input()
int_side = number
dec_side = ''
for i in range(0, len(number)):
    if number[i] == '.':
        int_side = number[:i]
        dec_side = number[i + 1:]
        break
while not (int_side.isdigit()) or not (dec_side.isdigit()) and dec_side != '':
    dec_side = ''
    print('Only numbers are allowed! (decimals included, but not fractions)')
    print('Type any number here: ')
    number = input()
    int_side = number
    for i in range(0, len(number)):
        if number[i] == '.':
            int_side = number[:i]
            dec_side = number[i + 1:]
    user_choice = input()
int_length = len(int_side)
ones = ['', 'one ', 'two ', 'three ', 'four ', 'five ', 'six ', 'seven ', 'eight ', 'nine ']
teens = ['ten ', 'eleven ', 'twelve ', 'thirteen ', 'fourteen ', 'fifteen ', 'sixteen ', 'seventeen ', 'eighteen ',
         'nineteen ']
decades = ['', '', 'twenty ', 'thirty ', 'forty ', 'fifty ', 'sixty ', 'seventy ', 'eighty ', 'ninety ']
hundreds = ['', 'one hundred ', 'two hundred ', 'three hundred ', 'four hundred ', 'five hundred ', 'six hundred ',
            'seven hundred ', 'eight hundred ', 'nine hundred ']
comma = ['thousand, ', 'million, ', 'trillion, ', 'quadrillion, ']
word = ''
int_length = len(int_side)
dec_length = len(dec_side)
change = int_length
up_change = 0
while change > 0:
    if int_side == '':
        break
    if number == '0':
        word = 'zero'
        break
    elif change > 1 and int_side[change - 2] == '1':
        for i in range(0, 10):
            if int_side[change - 1] == str(i):
                word = teens[i] + word
    else:
        if change > 0:
            for i in range(0, 10):
                if int_side[change - 1] == str(i):
                    word = ones[i] + word
        if change > 1:
            for i in range(0, 10):
                if int_side[change - 2] == str(i):
                    word = decades[i] + word
    if change > 2:
        for i in range(0, 10):
            if int_side[change - 3] == str(i):
                word = hundreds[i] + word
    if change > 3:
        word = comma[up_change] + word
    change -= 3
    up_change += 1
word += 'point '
for i in range(0, len(dec_side)):
    for x in range(0, 10):
        if dec_side[i] == str(x):
            word += ones[x]
print(word)
```

This is an example:

```
Type any number here: 13243214.1324hk
Only numbers are allowed! (decimals included, but not fractions)
Type any number here: 13243214.1324
thirteen million, two hundred forty three thousand, two hundred 
fourteen point one three two four
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def helper(number):
  num_words = {  
    0: "",  
    1: "one",  
    2: "two",
    3: "three",
    4: "four",
    5: "five",
    6: "six",
    7: "seven",
    8: "eight",
    9: "nine",
    10: "ten",
    11: "eleven",
    12: "twelve",
    13: "thirteen",
    14: "fourteen",
    15: "fifteen",
    16: "sixteen",
    17: "seventeen",
    18: "eighteen",
    19: "nineteen",
    20: "twenty",
    30: "thirty",
    40: "forty",
    50: "fifty",
    60: "sixty",
    70: "seventy",
    80: "eighty",
    90: "ninety",
    100: "hundred"
  }
  result = ""
  counter = 1
  while number > 0:
    r = number % 10 
    if counter < 100:
      result = num_words[r * counter] + " " + result
    else:
      result = num_words[r] + " " + num_words[counter] + " " + result
    number //= 10
    counter *= 10
  return result
  
def numToWords(number):
  thousand_illion = ["", "thousand ", "million ", "billion ", "trillion "]
  result = ""
  index = 0
  
  while number > 0:
    remainder = number % 1000
    result = helper(remainder) + thousand_illion[index] + result
    number //= 1000
    index += 1
  
  return result

number = 9_999_999_909_999
number = 45_109_704
print(numToWords(number))
```