# name of numbers in words // python 1 - 999

Tags: python, integer

I need to turn any number form 1 to 999 into written form. That means '1' to 'one' and '120' to 'one hundred and twenty.' I can write a really long list, but is there a better way? I'd appreciate it like a wild man if anyone could help.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: Also see Stack Overflow guidance on [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  Simply dumping your assignment here is unacceptable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109866/python-converting-numbers-to-words

Answer (score 0):

you can use `num2words`

```
>>> from num2words import num2words
>>> num2words(21)
twenty-one
```