# How to check if there are digits in a string, and speel them in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, function, integer

I am quite new to this programming world. I am wondering if we can check if we can spell out an integer from a string that was given in the input. For example, I am using the below to take an input and convert it to lowercase.

```
request = input('You: ').lower().strip()
```

What I want now is, if someone enters "300 years", it should be converted to "three hundred years", and then saved in the variable. Is it possible?

Comment: Take a look at the non-standard *inflect* module

Comment: I tied to use the inflect package, but it seems to be really incompatible with the rest of the code. It seems to delete some of my sample data. So, I am wondering for a custom function to achieve the same.

Comment: Show the code you used with *inflect*

Comment: Please remove your last comment and add the code to the question

Comment: Check out: [python: converting numbers to words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109866/python-converting-numbers-to-words/24123028#24123028)

Answer (score 0):

You could install *inflect* then, for example:

```
import inflect

engine = inflect.engine()

message = input('Type something: ')
output = []
for token in message.split():
    if token.isdecimal():
        output.append(engine.number_to_words(token))
    else:
        output.append(token)

print(' '.join(output))
```

**Console:**

```
Type something: 300 years
three hundred years
```